# What does なおも mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

What does なおも mean in the following sentence?

> 夜の十一時を過ぎるというのに、街は下品な化粧を塗りたくり、**なおも**喧騒に溢れていた 。

Can't find a definition on jisho.

Comment: Would this be of some help?
 https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/162809/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8A%E3%82%82/

Comment: Or [here](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%B0%9A%E3%82%82) in slightly more detail. Once you get to a level where you can start reading sentences like the one above, you should really consider reaching for a 国語辞典 first.

Comment: I don't know enough Japanese to read those links

Answer (score 2):

"In addition to that" is the best meaning for that in that sentence.

Comment: But why is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

夜の十一時を過ぎるというのに、なおも喧騒に溢れていた 。

なおも＝still

Answer (score -1):

When I put なおも喧騒 into google translate it says: "still noisy", so I take it to mean "still." Best I could find.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. `なおも` generally means "still". Possible synonyms would include `いまだに`, `依然として`, etc.

Comment: I agree with user23888.